# Unable to compare strings with lines in file

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a certain key exists in a file:

Here's how I'm storing keys into the file:

```
def cache_key(key):
    with open(file_name, "a") as processed:
            processed.write(key + "\n")
```

Here's how I'm comparing:

```
def check_key_exists(key):
    cache_file = open(file_name)
    for line in cache_file:
        if(str(line) == str(key)):
            cache_file.close()
            return True
    cache_file.close()
    return False


def some_func():
    for submission in subs.get_new(limit=75):
        if check_key_exists(submission.id):
            break
        else:
            do_something()
```

But even if the key exists within the file, `check_key_exists()` always returns `False`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `if line.strip() == str(key):`

Comment: Do you really want to open and close a file every time you need to check for a key? It would be faster to keep the `set` of existing keys in memory... (membership testing in a `set` is fast).

Comment: So should I copy the content of a file into a set and check from the set to compare?

Comment: @stack: If you call `check_key_exists()` often, then you could instead do `with open(filename) as cf: cache = {line.strip() for line in cf}` once and then just check `if key in cache:` everytime you need to do so. That way, you also avoid a costly function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has a newline character after each keyword (of course!), which I suppose is not part of your `key` parameter.

You could do

```
def check_key_exists(key):
    with open(file_name) as cache_file:
        for line in cache_file:
            if line.strip() == key:
                return True
    return False
```

Note that you don't need `str()` - your parameters should already be strings.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are adding a new line character at the end of your lines, you need to strip the lines, when you want to compare them with keys:

```
if (line.strip() == str(key)) :
```

Also note that if the `key` is a string you don't need to convert it to string by calling the `str()` function.